# Facebook get like count for search query

Tags: facebook, search, graph

I'm using `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post` to retrieve posts with query `watermelon`. Is it possible to also get the like count for the posts I retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likes element is returned for search result entries that have been liked.  Not all posts have been liked or the users permissions don't allow viewing of likes.  Here is a screenshot from the graph explorer though for your query which has some likes information:

[image: Facebook Search Results]

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook FQL does not have the feature of count, but you could always count the number of objects in the array with whatever language you are using.